# Abelian categories

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, abelian-categories

I am trying to understand the definition of abelian categories. I have found two different definitions which it seems they are not equivalent. If you think they are equivalent, then how can we prove that? And if they are not equivalent, then what is the right definition of abelian categories?

The first one is:
An abelian category is an additive category where
(i) every morphism admits a kernel and cokernel,
(ii) every monomorphism is a kernel and every epimorphism is a cokernel.

And the second one is:
An abelian category is an additive category where
(i) every morphism admits a kernel and cokernel,
(ii) every monomorphism is the kernel of its cokernel and every epimorphism is the cokernel of its kernel,
(iii) every morphism is expressible as the composite of an epimorphism and a monomorphism.

Comment: @user10354138 First I thought it can, but no it is not my question.

Comment: See Freyd's *Abelian Categories*.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I guess it say that the first definition implies the third part of the second definition.

Comment: Which is really all you have to prove : the first condition is the same in both definitions, and the second conditions of each are equivalent (given the first one).

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185870/in-an-abelian-category-every-kernel-is-kernel-of-cokernel?noredirect=1&lq=1) may help to understand my previous comment.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks for your comments. I found my answer by these two links but I guess the whole of the first definition implies the second condition of the first definition and the second conditions in these definitions are not equivalent.