# Are these two definitions of abelian categories equivalent?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Some sources define an abelian category as

> a pre-abelian category where every mono is the kernel of its cokernel and epi is the cokernel of its kernel.

Some other sources define an abelian category as

> a pre-abelian categories where every mono is a kernel and every epi a cokernel (not necessarily of their cokernel or kernel).

Are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: Have a look here at this site, it has been asked. See  [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782752/abelian-categories?noredirect=1&lq=1), or a similiar one.

Comment: Yes they are. It is not difficult to prove that $f$ is a kernel iff it's the kernel of its cokernel (and dually for cokernel)